# Nulls in spark.createDataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm writing a unit test that the test data need to have some null values.
I tried putting the nulls straight in the tuples and I also tried using Options. It didn't work out.

Here is my code:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
// Data set with null for even values
val sampleData = sparkSession.createDataset(Seq(
  (1, Some("Yes"), None),
  (2, None, None),
  (3, Some("Okay"), None),
  (4, None, None)))
  .toDF("id", "title", "value")
```

Stack trace:

```
None.type (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueSingleType)
scala.MatchError: None.type (of class scala.reflect.internal.Types$UniqueSingleType)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:596)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:587)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:49)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `None: Option[String]` instead of `None`

```
scala> val maybeString = None: Option[String]
maybeString: Option[String] = None

scala> val sampleData = spark.createDataset(Seq(
     |   (1, Some("Yes"), maybeString),
     |   (2, maybeString, maybeString),
     |   (3, Some("Okay"), maybeString),
     |   (4, maybeString, maybeString))).toDF("id", "title", "value")
sampleData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, title: string ... 1 more field]

scala> sampleData.show
+---+-----+-----+
| id|title|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|  Yes| null|
|  2| null| null|
|  3| Okay| null|
|  4| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Please put some efforts writing your answers ! I've edited with mine just because you have posted before me.

Comment: @eliasah The previous answer was sufficient I think.. But thanks for the details

Comment: It was sufficient for you :) But someone with less experience may not be able to understand that ! We write answers for the community and not just for the OP @aclokay

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use: `null.asInstanceOf[String]` If you're just dealing with Strings

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "Yes", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
     | (2, null.asInstanceOf[String], null.asInstanceOf[String]),
     | (3, "Okay", null.asInstanceOf[String]),
     | (4, null.asInstanceOf[String], null.asInstanceOf[String]))).toDF("id", "title", "value")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, title: string, value: string]

scala> df1.show
+---+-----+-----+
| id|title|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|  1|  Yes| null|
|  2| null| null|
|  3| Okay| null|
|  4| null| null|
+---+-----+-----+
```